# Problem with executing function which contains 3 other functions

Tags: javascript

I have problem with my bitcoin converter app. When I execute the function (which is linked to html button) called "converted", the first result is NaN, but after executing it again it works properly.

```
Live reload enabled.
index.js:39 NaN
index.js:26 218537
index.js:22 47628
index.js:39 0.0019946250104980264
index.js:22 47628
index.js:26 218537
```

I tried to use callback function in my code, to solve this problem, but it didn't change anything.

Here is the code:

```
let inputCash;
let exchangeRateEur;
let exchangeRatePln;
let afterConv;

function getRate(callback) {
    $.getJSON( "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/eur.json", function(data) {
    exchangeRateEur = parseInt(data.bpi.EUR.rate_float);
    console.log(exchangeRateEur);
    });
    $.getJSON( "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/pln.json", function(data) {
    exchangeRatePln = parseInt(data.bpi.PLN.rate_float);
    console.log(exchangeRatePln);
    });
    callback();
}

function getInputValue() {
    inputCash = document.getElementById("number").value;
}

function convert() {
    if ((document.getElementById("btn").innerText === 'EUR -> BTC')) {
        afterConv = inputCash / exchangeRateEur;
    }
    console.log(afterConv);
}

function converted() {
    getRate(getInputValue);
    convert();
}
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BTC Converter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="cointainer">
        <h1 class="title">btc converter</h1>
        <img src="gfx/btc.png" class="logo" alt="BTC Logo">
    </div>
    <div id="buttons" class="buttons">
        <button class="button" id="btn" onclick="changeButton(this.id)">EUR -> BTC</button>
    </div>
    <div class="display" name="converter">
        <input type="number" id="number" name="number">
        <input type="button" value="convert" onclick="converted();">
        <p>x</p>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try promise or async-await? It seems a timing issue you have. I think in the first call of function, you don't have any data from Coindesk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Your `getJson(), getJson(), callback()`, will actually execute in this order `callback(), getJson(), getJson()`..  Basically your calling callback before you get the results.   Follow the link I've posted for different options you can use.

Answer (score 0):

```
let inputCash;
let exchangeRateEur;
let exchangeRatePln;
let afterConv;
        
function getEuro(callback){
  $.getJSON( "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/eur.json", function(data) {
    exchangeRateEur = parseInt(data.bpi.EUR.rate_float);
    if(callback) callback();
 });
            
            }
        
 function getPLN(callback){
   $.getJSON( "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/pln.json", function(data) {
    exchangeRatePln = parseInt(data.bpi.PLN.rate_float);
    if(callback) callback();
 });
}
        
        
            
 function getRate(callback) {
  getEuro(()=>{
   getPLN(callBack);
   })
 }
            
 function getInputValue() {
   inputCash = document.getElementById("number").value;
   convert();
 }
            
 function convert() {
  if ((document.getElementById("btn").innerText === 'EUR -> BTC')) {
   afterConv = inputCash / exchangeRateEur;
  }
  console.log(afterConv);
 }
            
 function converted() {
   getRate(getInputValue);
 }
```

Or you could use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) async and await which is much better, [how to use fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)